# hiding referrer for all outbound links on page

Tags: php, html

I have a simple PHP page that has a tags (links) to different pages.
I want for the pages those links go to - not to be able to retrieve the http referrer.

in other words: I want to hide the referrer.

googling I found this to put in the  tag:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="none">
```

but it seems to not work on all browsers, mostly for those that don't support HTML5 so I need something better, and one that will work on mobile as well.

any ideas?

I also tried

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

in PHP but that seems to hide the referrer for HTTPS only, not HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Make your links of the form:

```
<a href="url" rel="noreferrer">Text</a>
```

This is part of the communication between the client (computer displaying the web page) and another web server, so PHP has nothing to do with it.